# I install react js but when in type npm start he give a error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

[This is a error i got from powershell]

npm ERR! code ENOENT

npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! path C:\Users\pawan gupta\Desktop\MY projects\Java script\react\package.json

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\pawan gupta\Desktop\MY projects\Java script\react\package.json'

npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.

npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\pawan gupta\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-07-30T13_27_23_480Z-debug.log

Comment: It looks like npm isn't able to find your project's package.json file. It would help if you can share what steps you have taken to create a new Node app with React. I can see from the logs there is a react directory (and this is where npm start is being executed from) but it isn't clear from your question if this is contains a node app.

Comment: Run the command npm start in the project's root directory

Comment: Thankx bro but my problem is solved now he is ruj perfectly